# PHP Session Variables in sql command becoming null when executed

Tags: php

Ok So I have a function that is executed after a customer purchases a digital code. The function is very simple and uses pdo after I thought that would fix it instead of using mysqli. everything works but the username variable does not get put in the table even thought I can echo it out and use it in other sql command just fine but for some reason not this particular line.

Here is the code:

```
function redeemToken($amount = 1){
    $db_tokens = new PDO('mysql:host=IP;dbname=DB', "U", "P");
    $qOne = $db_tokens->query("SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE used='0' LIMIT $amount;"); //selects the first unused token
    $dataToken = $qOne->fetch();
    $token = $dataToken["token"];
    $qTwo = $db_tokens->query("UPDATE tokens SET used='1', usedby='".$php_session_username."', date_used=NOW() WHERE token='".$token."';"); //uses the token for the current logged in user
    $db_kvs = null;
}
```

As I stated everything is executed fine except for the fact that the username value ($php_session_username) does not get added into the table. but when echo'd out shows the logged in users name clearly as well as with any other sql command I run on that page; it works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated so thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the account you're running the query as has `UPDATE` rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but I guess the problem is that $php_session_username is not the function's local variable and neither the function is getting it value in its parameter. Try something like this.

```
function redeemToken($amount = 1,$php_session_username)
{
//function body
}
($amount = 1,$php_session_username);
```

Comment: Yeah it was something like that. I was passing the session username to a variable and using the variable defined outside the brackets. I fixed it now. Thanks

Comment: If you find the answer useful, mark it as correct :)